# What do the arguments mean between the < >?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am looking at code related to the Parse framework.

What would the following mean, particularly referring to the parameters in the < , > ?

```
@interface AppDelegate()<PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>
```

This is a question moreso related to Objective-C than Parse itself, although knowing Parse may help answer my question more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Those are Protocols that the AppDelegate class conforms to.

Comment: This is the answer you were looking for. The items between the brackets are the protocols your class conforms to.